# Is reCAPTCHA's data used to improve any OCR software?

Tags: ocr, recaptcha

reCAPTCHA is used in lots of places and no doubt has a massive amount of data of 'bad looking image' to 'word'. This sort of data could be used to make really good OCR software. So is there any OCR software that is using this data?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly as a training data, I doubt there's a way to find out. But basically, it is you to be used as an OCR software (your input - if confirmed - is used to decode OCR-unreadable words in scanned books).

Answer (score 1):

doubt it. i was gonna answer that if google would release data associated with recaptcha it probably would turn against them. but in reality anyony can train it's own neural network to do what google does; the problem is, that many images served by recaptcha are in so bad quality, that taking any conclusions (or traning naural networks) from this images would produce very high false-positive results

Comment: I would think that the sheer quantity of data would make recaptcha data valuable. Anyone can do a training system. But you can't do it 100 million a day.

Comment: it probably would, but from most of that data you can't take any conclusions - that's why google serves what they can't ocr for people to do

Comment: You can draw conclusions from it. The 'can't ocr' text is text that is hard to OCR, and then people write in what it is. You can use this data (image & corrected text) to train your OCR system to be better.